# Windows10でスクリーンショットを撮った後に切り取り＆スケッチを自動起動するには

Tags: windows, windows-10

[「Snipping Tool」は廃止へ ～「Windows 10 RS5」でスクショの取り方はこうなる！ - 窓の杜](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/serial/yajiuma/1131054.html)

に

> 最後の問題に対する答えは、キャプチャーしたあとに表示される編集・保存アプリです。このアプリではペンを利用した注釈機能（指も利用可能）、物差し機能、クロッピング（切り抜き）機能などが利用可能。ファイルへの保存はもちろん、クリップボードへのコピーや［共有］コマンドを介した他アプリとの連携なども行えます。

とありますが、WIN+SHIFT+Sで撮影してもキャプチャーしたあとに表示される編集・保存アプリが表示されません

どうすればWindows10でスクリーンショットを撮った後に切り取り＆スケッチ（編集・保存アプリ）を自動起動できますか？

Comment: アプリ自体は表示されませんが、デフォルトの通知設定であれば画面の右下に通知ウインドウが表示されますので、そこから起動できます。URL先の文言で勝手にアプリが上がってくる印象を受けますが、「通知」画像を載せてますので、そこから起動するのではないかと推測します。

Comment: wakuwakuさんの発言通り右下に表示される画像のタイルをクリックすると「切り取り & スケッチ」が起動します。バージョンは1903です。個人的にはCtrl+Alt+PrintScreenの方が好きですけど。

Comment: wakuwaku さんと Uncle-Kei さん、コメントでの情報共有ありがとうございます！　ただ、コメントは回答と違って編集に制限があったり簡単に削除できたりするので、このような内容でしたら回答の方が向いているかと思います。また、もしよろしければ今回なぜ回答ではなくコメントとして投稿されたのか、[こちらの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3242/19110)に寄稿いただけないでしょうか。決して責めている訳では無く、使い分けをシステムとしてどのように対処すべきか考えあぐねており、まずはご意見を募集している段階です。もしお時間あればご協力いただけると幸いです<(\_ \_)>

Comment: 質問で求めているのがキャプチャ後に「自動起動」だからではないでしょうか。

Comment: nekketsuuuさんへ。自分のコメント内容はwakuwakuさんの「コメント」に対する補足にすぎません。当然ですが回答者の求める解決とも直結しません。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さんへ。私の方は推測であり、「自動起動」に対する回答ではなかったのでコメントと致しました。

Comment: お二方とも教えてくださりありがとうございます。[こちら](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3255/19110)に事例として蓄積させていただきました。とても助かります……！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> でスクリーンショットを起動した場合、撮影後に出てくる通知をクリックすることで「切り取り＆スケッチ」が起動します。

  [image]
- 「切り取り＆スケッチ」の「新規」ボタンからスクリーンショットを撮った場合、撮影後自動的に「切り取り＆スケッチ」に戻ってきます。

  [image]

動作を確認した環境：Windows 10 Home 1903

Answer (score 1):

Windows 標準機能ではなく、**専用のキャプチャ用アプリ** を使えば、スクリーンショットの取得後にそのまま編集画面を開くことができます (編集せずに画像を保存する、Webストレージへのアップロード等も可)。

私が個人的に最近使用しているのは [PicPick](https://picpick.app/en/) というアプリです。

Answer (score -1):

質問に書かれているURLは、Windows Insider Programという、Windowsの開発に協力する人たちのコミュニティ(Microsoftが運営)の記事なので、まだ開発中か、Windows Insider Programに参加している人たちがテストや評価をしている途中なのだと思います（まだ正式にアナウンスされていない試作品という感じです）。

将来、記事に書かれているような事が出来るようになるかもしれませんが、リリースされないまま消えていく可能性もあります。

待つしかないですね。

Comment: 「切り取り＆スケッチ」自体は既に通常の最新版 Windows 10 にて使えるようになっています。